# Как создать светофор в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Наткнулся на код рабочего светофора, но не могу понять как он работает.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class QT_TrafficLight : MonoBehaviour {
    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject BulbGreen,BulbYellow,BulbRed;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool showLinks=false;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Color linkColor;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector3 controllerPosition;
    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject[] Lights = new GameObject[3];
    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
    foreach(Transform t in transform)
        {
            if(t.name.Contains("BulbGreen"))
                BulbGreen = t.gameObject;
            if(t.name.Contains("BulbRed"))
                BulbRed = t.gameObject;
            if(t.name.Contains("BulbYellow"))
                BulbYellow = t.gameObject;
            if(t.name.Contains("Light-BulbGreen"))
                Lights[0]=t.gameObject;
            if(t.name.Contains("Light-BulbYellow"))
                Lights[1] = t.gameObject;
            if(t.name.Contains("Light-BulbRed"))
                Lights[2] = t.gameObject;

        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(showLinks)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(this.transform.position,controllerPosition,linkColor);

        }
    }
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста.

> Что делает Debug.DrawLine в данном случае

Comment: Попробую пояснить. В вашем коде всего навсего происходит инициализация ссылок на ваши лампочки. Лампочки светофора - это дочерние компоненты GameObject-а, на котором находится ваш MonoBehaviour с именем QT_TrafficLight. Сам код, который вы привели - НИКАК не меняет светофор, и уж тем более, не делает этого с помощью Debug.DrawLine. Отрисовка линии - всего навсего, показывает наличие связи между двумя Transform объектами, когда вы ставите флаг showLinks. Подозреваю, что вы упустили суть, которая находится в других объектах и в Editor классах.

Comment: Подведу итоги - вы привели не код светофора.

Comment: Еще одна версия, переключение у вас вполне возможно выполняется через аниматор) и никакого скрипта управляющего светофором нет)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно **[документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html)**, `Debug.DrawLine` рисует линию между двумя указанными точками.

- Первый аргумент - координаты начала линии
- Второй аргумент - координаты конца линии
- Третий - цвет линии

`this.transform.position` - позиция объекта на котором висит этот самый скрипт

`controllerPosition` - позиция объекта, который будет добавлен, например через инспектор (правда пока непонятно где он у вас, ибо через инспектор вы его не добавите имея атрибут `HideInInspector`)

`linkColor` - тот самый цвет. Аналогично предыдущей переменной - нигде в коде у вас цвет не присваивается на данный момент

Comment: Этот скрипт находится на светофоре, оказалось строки (Light-BulbYellow) это названия GameObject-ов на которых есть свет, просто там не понятно как менется цвет, получается его меняет `Debug.DrawLine ` а как время расчитывается может подскажете.

Comment: @Abs3akt какое время?

Comment: время когда меняется свет светофора, по этому скрипту он меняется)  но так как этот скрипт не мой не могу толком понять что происходит, да и спасибо.

Comment: @Abs3akt ничего не вижу указывающее на временные метки. Всё что вижу это флаг `showLinks` и если он `true`, то срабатывает условие. Возможно где-то еще есть какие-нибудь триггеры для срабатывания. Но  в данном скрипте ничего толком нет

Comment: >>нигде в коде у вас цвет не присваивается на данный момент<< Присваивается. Скорее всего в инспекторе. Менее вероятно, но так же имеет место быть, что значения инициализируются в CustomEditor классе.

Comment: @Abs3akt >>получается его меняет<< - ни в коем случае. Его никто не меняет в вашем коде. Ищите другие скрипты, предположу что они находятся на самих объектах-источниках света.

Comment: @test123 `Скорее всего в инспекторе` - **в данном** коде это невозможно, т.к. атрибут `[HideInInspector]` чётко дает понять о том, что поле **спрятано в инспекторе**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, А мне не даёт понять. Есть рефлексия, есть CustomEditor, я проходил это несколько раз :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, плюс, поля публичные, их может менять кто угодно извне.

Comment: @test123 еще раз: **в данном** коде поле **спрятано в инспекторе** поэтому "Присваивается. Скорее всего в инспекторе" - **не выполняется**. Точка!....мы говорили об этом.... Причём тут рефлексия, менять где угодно извне и санта клаус с оленями - мне  непонятно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский >>не выполняется<< Точно, я не прав. Прошу прощения.

Answer (score 1):

Когда то делал для тренажера контроллер светофора.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TrafficLightController : MonoBehaviour {

public bool isWork = true;
public bool isWaiting = false;
private bool lastWork;
private bool lastWaiting;
public GameObject waitingRegim;
public float TimeFlash = 0.5f;
public int regimeCount = 1;
public float StartTimeOn = 0;
public int StartRegimOn = 0;
public float[] timesSwitch = new float[1];
public GameObject[] objectsSwitch = new GameObject[1];
public bool[] flashRegim = new bool[1];  
private float timeWork;
private int regimWork;
private bool lightFlashOn;
private float timeFlash;
private bool isOk = true;
// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
    isOk = true;

    if (regimeCount < 1)
        isOk = SL_Util.CheckFailed("Traffic Light are not initialization.") && isOk;

    if (timesSwitch.Length != regimeCount)
        isOk = SL_Util.CheckFailed("Traffic Light are not synchronization by Times Switch.") && isOk;

    if (objectsSwitch.Length != regimeCount)
        isOk = SL_Util.CheckFailed("Traffic Light are not synchronization by Objects Switch.") && isOk;

    if (flashRegim.Length != regimeCount)
        isOk = SL_Util.CheckFailed("Traffic Light are not synchronization by Flash Regim.") && isOk;

    if (StartRegimOn >= regimeCount || StartRegimOn < 0)
        isOk = SL_Util.CheckFailed("Start Regim are not correct for Traffic Light.") && isOk;

    for (int i=0; i < timesSwitch.Length; i++){
        if (timesSwitch[i] <= 0)
            isOk = SL_Util.CheckFailed("Traffic Light need setting Times switch.") && isOk;
    }
    regimWork = StartRegimOn;
    timeWork = StartTimeOn;
    lightFlashOn = true;

    lastWork = !isWork;
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (!isOk)
        return;

    switchRegim();

    if (isWork == false)
        return;

    float delta = Time.deltaTime;

    if (isWaiting == false){
        int newRegim = regimWork;
        timeWork -= delta;
        while (timeWork <= 0){
            newRegim++;
            if (newRegim >= timesSwitch.Length)
                newRegim = 0;

            timeWork += timesSwitch[newRegim];
        }
        if (newRegim != regimWork){
            switchObject(objectsSwitch[regimWork], false);
            switchObject(objectsSwitch[newRegim], true);
            regimWork = newRegim;
            lightFlashOn = true;
            timeFlash = TimeFlash;
            return;
        }
    }

    if (isWaiting || flashRegim[regimWork]){
        bool newLightFlashOn = lightFlashOn;
        timeFlash -= delta;
        while (timeFlash <= 0){
            newLightFlashOn = !newLightFlashOn;
            timeFlash += TimeFlash;
        }
        if (newLightFlashOn != lightFlashOn){
            if (isWaiting){
                switchObject(waitingRegim, newLightFlashOn);
            } else {
                switchObject(objectsSwitch[regimWork], newLightFlashOn);
            }

            lightFlashOn = newLightFlashOn;
        }
    }

}

void switchObject(GameObject  obj, bool newValue){
    if (obj != null)
        obj.SetActiveRecursively(newValue);
}

void switchRegim(){
    if (isWaiting != lastWaiting || isWork != lastWork){
        //if (isWaiting != lastWaiting){
            regimWork = StartRegimOn;
        //}
        lastWork = isWork;
        lastWaiting = isWaiting;
        foreach(GameObject obj in objectsSwitch){
            switchObject(obj, false);
        }

        if (isWork == false)
            return;

        if (isWaiting){
            switchObject(waitingRegim, true);
        } else {
            switchObject(objectsSwitch[regimWork], true);
        }
    }
}

}
```

функция `SL_Util.CheckFailed(errormessage)` возвращает ложь и выводит сообщение в лог, можно закомментировать если лень писать свою (просто присвойте `isOk = False`)

Тренажер может работать в режиме рабочем или ожидания. При этом сигнал может показываться постоянно или моргать. Переключаются сигналы по настроенным интервалам.

Массивы для настройки режимов.

`timesSwitch` - время режимов по секундам

`objectsSwitch` - объект который должен включиться в данном режиме

`flashRegim` - признак того должен ли моргать объект.

Таким образом можно настроить светофор на работу в заданном режиме. Писал скрипт на Unity 3.5 еще, так что пишу как работал по памяти.